# csv file does not write while in 'w' mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with csv file in write mode it doesn't write the file successfully

```
import csv
import json

result_log={'url':'http://google.com','timeSeries':'2019, 6, 3, 10, 29, 10'}
rows = json.loads(str(result_log))

r = zip(*rows.values())
fieldnames = ['url', 'timeSeries']
with open('process_upc.csv', 'w') as f:
dict_writer = csv.writer(f)
dict_writer.writerow(fieldnames)
for d in r:
    dict_writer.writerow(d)
```

output:Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: What is your expected csv output? @SudheerReddy ? See if my answer below makes sense to you

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to convert your dictionary to a string via `json.loads`, you can use your dictionary as is when writing to csv.
- If you want to convert your dictionary to a string, you should do `json.dumps(result_log)` instead
- To get the values of the dictionary, you can just do `result_log.values()`, and you would want to write the values in one single `writerow` call

Hence your updated code will be

```
import csv
import json

result_log={"url":"http://google.com","timeSeries":"2019, 6, 3, 10, 29, 10"}

#Get the values of the dictionary
r = result_log.values()
fieldnames = ['url', 'timeSeries']
with open('process_upc.csv', 'w') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.writer(f)
    dict_writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    #Write the values to csv
    dict_writer.writerow(r)
```

And the output will be

```
url,timeSeries
http://google.com,"2019, 6, 3, 10, 29, 10"
```